# How can i assign an interface object to dynamic object in a method?

Tags: c#, object, methods, dynamic

I am trying to create a function for assigning interface objects to dynamic objects which I created in my struct easily. Here is my struct:

```
public struct PSU
{
    public CheckBox CallHostessButton0, CallHostessButton1,
        ReadLightButton0, ReadLightButton1, ReadLightButton2, ReadLightButton3;
    public PictureBox BeltLight, SmokeLight;
}
```

And here is my function:

```
public void AssignObjectsToPSU(UniversalVariables.PSU psu, CheckBox 
CallHostessBtn0, EventHandler HBtn0CheckedChanged, CheckBox 
CallHostessBtn1, EventHandler HBtn1CheckedChanged)
{
// and i'm trying to do this in my function:
...
psu.CallHostessButton0 = CallHostessBtn0;
psu.CallHostessButton0.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(HBtn0CheckedChanged); 
...
}
```

The program runs smoothly but when I try to do this in CheckedChanged event:

```
if (TestPSU.CallHostessButton0.Checked)
{
    TestPSU.CallHostessButton0.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.lamp_on;
}
else
{
    TestPSU.CallHostessButton0.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.lamp_off;
}
```

Program gives an error that:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in IOS_Interface.exe
TestPSU.**CallHostessButton0** was null.
```

How can it be null? I'm assigning this on my `AssignObjectsToPSU` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just changed struct type to class and it worked.

I changed these:

```
public struct PSU
{
     public CheckBox CallHostessButton0, CallHostessButton1,
     ReadLightButton0, ReadLightButton1, ReadLightButton2, ReadLightButton3;
     public PictureBox BeltLight, SmokeLight;
 }

 public void AssignObjectsToPSU(UniversalVariables.PSU psu, CheckBox 
 CallHostessBtn0, EventHandler HBtn0CheckedChanged, CheckBox 
 CallHostessBtn1, EventHandler HBtn1CheckedChanged)
 {
 // and i'm trying to do this in my function:
 ...
 psu.CallHostessButton0 = CallHostessBtn0;
 psu.CallHostessButton0.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(HBtn0CheckedChanged); 
 ...
 }
```

to this:

```
//UniversalVariables.cs
public class PSU
{
    public CheckBox CallHostessButton0, CallHostessButton1,
        ReadLightButton0, ReadLightButton1, ReadLightButton2, ReadLightButton3;
    public PictureBox BeltLight, SmokeLight;

    public PSU(CheckBox CallHostBtn0, CheckBox CallHostBtn1, CheckBox ReadLightBtn0, CheckBox ReadLightBtn1,
        PictureBox BeltLght, PictureBox SmokeLght, [Optional] CheckBox ReadLightBtn2, [Optional] CheckBox ReadLightBtn3)
    {
        Log("[Info] Assigning objects to PSU unit...");
        CallHostessButton0 = CallHostBtn0;
        CallHostessButton1 = CallHostBtn1;
        ReadLightButton0 = ReadLightBtn0;
        ReadLightButton1 = ReadLightBtn1;

        if (CallHostessButton0 == null || CallHostessButton1 == null || ReadLightButton1 == null || ReadLightButton0 == null)
        {
            LogReport("[Failed]");
        }

        else { LogReport("[OK]"); }

        if (ReadLightBtn2 != null)
        {
            Log(String.Format("[Info] Extra {0} detected...", nameof(ReadLightBtn2)));
            this.ReadLightButton2 = ReadLightBtn2;
            LogReport("[OK]");

            if(ReadLightBtn3 != null)
            {
                Log(String.Format("[Info] Extra {0} detected...", nameof(ReadLightBtn3)));
                this.ReadLightButton3 = ReadLightBtn3;
                LogReport("[OK]");
            }
        }

        this.BeltLight = BeltLght; this.SmokeLight = SmokeLght;
    }
```

When you want to define new PSU, you just need to do it in your form's code like this:

```
 // Interface.cs
 UniversalVariables.PSU[] TestPSU = new UniversalVariables.PSU()cb_CallHost0, cb_CallHost1, cb_ReadLight0, cb_ReadLight1, pb_BeltLghtTest, pb_SmkLghtTest);
```

Or you need an array of PSU (Or something like this for your project):

```
 //Interface.cs
 UniversalVariables.PSU[] TestPSU = new UniversalVariables.PSU[12];
 TestPSU[<indexOfYourPSU>] = new UniversalVariables.PSU(cb_CallHost0, cb_CallHost1, cb_ReadLight0, cb_ReadLight1, pb_BeltLghtTest, pb_SmkLghtTest);
```

And it worked successfully :) I hope this experience will help someone. Have a good day...